# Condiciones múltiples bash

Tags: linux, bash, condiciones

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
  cat <<-EOF
MENÚ DE COPIAS DE SEGURIDAD
1       Copia manual de un directorio
2       Copia manual de un fichero
3       Añadir tareas a CRON
4       Ver lista de tareas automatizadas de CRON
5       Salir
EOF
  read respuesta

  case $respuesta in
    1)  echo "Introduzca el directorio de origen"
                read directorio
        echo "Introduzca la ruta de destino"
                read destino
                        if [ -d $directorio ] && [ -d $destino ]
                                then
                                        cp -r $directorio $destino
                        else
                                echo "Introduzca una ruta válida"
                        fi;;
    2) echo "Introduzca el directorio de origen del fichero"
        read fichero
        echo "Introduzca la ruta de destino"
        read destinof
                if [ -d $fichero ] && [ -d $destinof ]
                        then
                                cp -r $fichero $destinof
                else
                        echo "Se ha equivocado"
                fi;;
    3) echo "Bienvenido a CRON"
        crontab -e;;
    4) echo "Lista de tareas activas:"
        crontab -l;;
    5) echo "Hasta luego"
        exit;;
    *) echo "Debe escoger una opción válida";;
  esac
done
```

Pero a la hora de ejecutarlo, me da error en línea 29, creo que es por la condición múltiple del IF, pero no estoy seguro.
Edito: el error es exactamente este:

`copiaseguridad.sh: 29: [: "/home/rafa/Documentos/Hacklab: unexpected operator`

Comment: En qué linea? Creo que no me falta nada

Comment: Utiliza **comillas dobles** cuando manejes el valor de las variables. Pon `[ -d "$fichero" ] && [ -d "$destinof" ]`. Comprueba si `[ -d 1 2 ]` da el mismo mensaje de error que el que obtienes al ejecutar el script..

Comment: Cuando pueda lo pruebo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un problema con rutas que contengan espacios en blanco (tanto en el nombre del directorio como del archivo).

Lo puedes solucionar delimitando el contenido de las variables (uses o no la forma que te dice @PaulRM) de la siguiente manera:

```
[ -d "$fichero" ] && [ -d "$destinof" ]
```

Ojo, no he corregido el tipo de prueba (`-d` para comprobar existencia de directorios y `-f` para archivos).

Igualmente deberías delimitar líneas en las que uses dichas rutas como parámetros, como ésta:

```
cp -r "$fichero" "$destinof"
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia la linea 29

```
if [ -d $fichero ] && [ -d $destinof ]
```

a

```
if [ -f $fichero -a -d $destinof ]
```

Comment: ambos operadores -a y && son validos. no creo que sea el problema

Comment: No funciona, sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: @ras212 no entiendo como tienes el mismo error, pero por otro lado veo que: en la linea 29, preguntas por un fichero con -d

`if [ -d $fichero ] `

debería ser 

`if [ -f $fichero ] `

Comment: @PaulRM -d sirve para comprobar que exista el fichero y ademas sea directorio (carpeta).Su variable la llamó fichero (desafortunadamente) porque "Introduzca el directorio de origen del fichero". -f es para comprobar que exista y sea archivo regular. http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Comment: Efectivamente, eso es lo que quería decir

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la solución:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
  cat <<-EOF
MENÚ DE COPIAS DE SEGURIDAD
1   Copia manual de un directorio
2   Copia manual de un fichero
3   Añadir tareas a CRON
4   Ver lista de tareas automatizadas de CRON
5   Salir
EOF
  read respuesta

  case $respuesta in
    1)  echo "Introduzca el directorio de origen"
        read directorio
    echo "Introduzca la ruta de destino"
        read destino
            if [ -d $directorio ] && [ -d $destino ]
                then
                    cp -r $directorio $destino
            else
                echo "Introduzca una ruta válida"
            fi;;
    2) echo "Introduzca el directorio de origen del fichero"
    read fichero
    echo "Introduzca la ruta de destino"
    read destinof
        if [ -f $fichero ] && [ -d $destinof ]
            then
                cp -r $fichero $destinof
        else
            echo "Se ha equivocado"5
        fi;;
    3) echo "Bienvenido a CRON"
    crontab -e;;
    4) echo "Lista de tareas activas:"
    crontab -l;;
    5) echo "Hasta luego"
    exit;;
    *) echo "Debe escoger una opción válida";;
  esac
done
```

Prueba:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿"Ésta es la solución"? ¿Qué has cambiado para arreglarlo?

Comment: He puesto los parámetros -d y -f bien. ese era el error. No me di cuenta

Comment: Es que copié y pegué tu script en mi máquina para reproducir tu problema y únicamente salía tu error si ponía rutas con espacios en blanco (pongo `/tmp mal` como ruta): `pruebas.sh: línea 29: [: /tmp: se esperaba un operador binario`. Si hago la modificación que tú dices sigue fallando en exactamente en la misma línea con el mismo mensaje de error. A parte de eso, si fue @PaulRM quien te dio con la solución, deberías haber votado su respuesta como la correcta y darle los puntos de reputación a él.

Comment: Yo puse la ruta entre comillas

Comment: ¿Y poniendo la ruta entre comillas eres capaz de reproducir el problema que tenías planteado originalmente?

Comment: Evité el problema de la ruta, luego cambié esa línea de código.

Comment: Entonces, ¿qué tiene que ver tu respuesta con la pregunta planteada originalmente? Evitas el problema de la ruta usando mi solución de forma indirecta (en vez de entrecomillar la variable entrecomillas la ruta introducida) y tu solución (cambiar `-d` por `-f`) soluciona un problema totalmente ajeno a la pregunta que planteaste, no tiene nada que ver con el mensaje de error que te salía.

Comment: Acabo de volver a reproducir el problema introduciendo las rutas entre comillas, por lo que esa no es una solución. Hay que poner entre comillas las variables en los `if` y no introducir las rutas entre comillas. Por eso te debería seguir fallando tu script. Acabo de copiar/pegar este script, el que dices que arregla el problema, y al poner archivos o directorios entre comillas da fallo porque no existen rutas que contengan esas comillas (las considera parte de la ruta), y si pongo un espacio en blanco (aunque sea entre comillas) vuelve a salir el mensaje de error que planteas en la pregunta.

Comment: Ahora lo probaré otra vez, quizá me habré equivocado al pegar el código

Comment: Te pongo captura de que va

Comment: sin embargo, al poner las comillas en los me dice que me he equivocado

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48004/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-ras212).